# A priori estimates for elliptic operators

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, elliptic-pde

Suppose $L : L^{m,p}(M)\rightarrow L^p(M)$ is some elliptic operator of order $m$, and $(M,g)$ is a compact Riemannian manifold. Then it is known that there exists a constant $C$ such that we have the a priori estimates $$\|u\|_{L^{k,m}}\leq C(\|u\|_{L^p} + \|Lu\|_{L^p}).$$ From this it follows that there exists a constant $C^\prime$ such that for all $u\perp Ker(L)$, $$\|u\|_{L^{k,m}}\leq C^\prime\|Lu\|_{L^p}.$$ The only way I know to prove this is by a contradiction argument which also uses the fact that $L^{m,p}\hookrightarrow L^p$is a compact embedding. The question is the following - Is there a way to exactly see the dependence of $C^\prime$ on $C$ (and maybe the constant in the compact embedding)? Or is there a proof that is more constructive, and not relying on a contradiction argument? Any references would be appreciated!

I am actually working on a gluing problem wherein I need to control the inverse of the linearized operator (orthogonal to the kernel). I can get the first inequality with the constant independent of the gluing parameter $t$. To control the inverse, I need to understand how the $C^\prime$ depends on this $t$.

Answer (score 1):

See for instance the book of Warner Foundations of Differentiable Manifolds and Lie Groups 6.29 fundamental inequality.